# IO.popen with MySql (MariaDB) in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, pipe, mariadb, popen

before I start describing my problem I'd like to point out that I'm bound to ruby version 1.8.6 (to explain why is out of the scope of this thread). Hence I can't use gem modules like mysql, mysql2.

What I'm trying to achieve is to write a ruby program which interacts which a MySQL Database on a remote server (in this particular case MariaDB monitor as monitoring module -> s.picture)

I manage to get the following code running:

```
command=String.new("mysql -h hostadress --protocol tcp --user=uname --password=passw dbname")
connection=IO.popen(command,'r+')     
connection.puts("SELECT \*FROM table WHERE name=\"match\" \\g")
connection.close_write
data=connection.read
p data

connection=IO.popen(command,'r+')     
connection.puts("SELECT \*FROM table WHERE name=\"match2\"\\g")
connection.close_write
data=connection.read
p data
```

But as you can see, it's very ugly since I have to open the database again and again (I'm doing this a lot in my actual script). Is there an elegant solution to only open the database once (e.g reopen the pipe)?
[image]

Comment: I don't thing a pipe is the right way to connect to MySQL.  Did you install `libmysql-ruby`, `libmysqlcliient-dev` and "gem rails rake mysql"?

Comment: See also http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=27052&group_id=1598&atid=6231

Comment: Hi, your second link doesn't seem to work currently. Libmysql sseems to be for Linux OS only (I'm on windows)? https://pkgs.org/download/libmysql-ruby